# How do I call a class function and use the return value in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got a custom glass-like button that, when pressed, shows a black background. That's fine, but I was hoping for something more. I want to, rather than show the background as black, show the background as something derived from the actual background color of the button.

Is it possible, from the XAML, to call a function, pass the background color, and use the return value in the trigger?

This is what I have now

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Glow" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Shine" Value="0.4"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#CC000000"/>
</Trigger>
```

And this is what I would like -

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Glow" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Shine" Value="0.4"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{GetColor(Border.Background)}"/>
</Trigger>
```

How can I make that happen?

### EDIT

It was suggested I should use a ValueConverter : I have since implemented one here :

```
public class PRBGConverter : IValueConverter {
    public object Convert( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture ) {
        Console.WriteLine( "Clicked!" );
        if ( value is SolidColorBrush ) {
            SolidColorBrush SCB = value as SolidColorBrush;
            SCB.Color = Color.FromArgb( 0xCC, SCB.Color.R, SCB.Color.G, SCB.Color.B );
            return SCB;
        } else if ( value is GradientBrush ) {
            GradientBrush GB = value as GradientBrush;
            foreach ( GradientStop GS in GB.GradientStops )
                GS.Color = Color.FromArgb( 0xCC, GS.Color.R, GS.Color.G, GS.Color.B );
            return GB;
        } else return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture ) {
        Console.WriteLine( "UnClicked!" );
        if ( value is SolidColorBrush ) {
            SolidColorBrush SCB = value as SolidColorBrush;
            SCB.Color = Color.FromArgb( 0x99, SCB.Color.R, SCB.Color.G, SCB.Color.B );
            return SCB;
        } else if ( value is GradientBrush ) {
            GradientBrush GB = value as GradientBrush;
            foreach ( GradientStop GS in GB.GradientStops )
                GS.Color = Color.FromArgb( 0x99, GS.Color.R, GS.Color.G, GS.Color.B );
            return GB;
        } else
            return value;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, as evidenced by the console debug output, the ConvertBack method is never called, resulting in a pressed button background remaining opaque - how do I correct this?

XAML -

```
<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Glow" Value="Hidden"/>
    <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="Shine" Value="0.4"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Binding ElementName="Border" Path="Background" Converter="{StaticResource BGConverter}" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>                                 
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Trigger>
```

Comment: You can use Converters..http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly for what I was looking. Question though - how do I reset the background once the mouse button has been released? I would think the 'ConvertBack' method would handle that, but it does not seem to be doing so... the background stays opaque when it should become more transparent - see update...

Comment: You need to use the ConvertBack is another way of doing it. You can set it back by writing another trigger. <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="False">....Set the original color...</Trigger>

Comment: Then what is the purpose of the ConvertBack method? I was afraid that I would have to write another trigger, which is not a huge deal, but what function does the ConvertBack method serve, and how would I trigger it?

Comment: The Convertback comes in handy when you make use of a Two Way binding in combination with the Converter. So the Convert function handles manipulation from source to UI. The ConvertBack function handles reverting the manipulation from UI to source.

Comment: @Bart thank you for nice explaination.

Comment: @Will hope you understood. Make sure you get the complete idea of Data Binding in WPF.

Comment: Yes that helps thanks; Unfortunately your suggestion of implementing another trigger did not work - The incoming object is null on load, resulting in all buttons getting no background at all.
EDIT - I figured it out - the best way is to toggle based on the value of the alpha of the incoming brush. Thanks for the help.